# Anatomically Correct "Thirds"

Tags: science-fiction, reproduction, android

The concept of "Thirds" comes from the anime OVA series, "Armitage III". Basically, the people of Mars designed robotic women that were actually capable of getting pregnant and giving birth to human children to help boost the population enough to declare independence (there *was* a male version, with only one known individual, made though).

The question I want to answer here is how might their artificial reproductive systems work. Presumably, they'd want to avoid just cloning the reproductive organs of women already on Mars to avoid potential issues with limiting the gene pool, so how might they go about it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a natural part of the [anatomically correct series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series?noredirect=1#comment17888_2797) as it's asking after an artificial life form, which can't be "anatomically correct" from an evolutionary perspective by definition.

Comment: What's wrong with the reproductive organs of women? They are doing an excellent job for thousands years....

Comment: And why would one even need a whole robot, when you can have brainless [synthetic womb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dt7twXzNEsQ) that works all right?

Comment: @Mołot: Motivation ;-)

Comment: @nzaman Sperm donation would be much more efficient :(

Comment: @Mołot: But would sperm banks have people lining up to deposit?

Comment: @nzaman If it is a national effort? Yes, probably. And you could use sexy robots just to collect sperm. Well, you could even simply use prostitutes for that.

Comment: This doesn't explain the limitations under which we are operating.  How many unrelated "real" women are on Mars to contribute genetic material?  Can they obtain genetic material from somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

However you do this, it's going to involve technology significantly beyond what we have nowadays.

The best option is likely not robots but artificial uteruses. There's already significant research being invested into growing artificial organs for transplants. Once that was perfected, your future-humans started working on avoiding all the problems and complications of pregnancy and birth in space. And they invented artificial reproductive organs for that purpose.

By this point, genetic engineering has also been developed far beyond what we currently have, and computer memory has continued to increase exponentially. So they could store and use the sequenced genomes of as many people from Earth as they wanted. (Which ones are chosen for reproduction brings up all sorts of ethical issues, since it can border on eugenics, so that could become a plot point.)

EDIT: It's been pointed out (thanks to Mołot) that artificial uteruses do, in fact, already exist! Science marches on…of course, they're still far from ready for human reproduction, but they've been used very successfully in animal experiments.

Comment: As I've commented  above [artificial uterus is real nowadays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dt7twXzNEsQ). It has some drawbacks  and only works for the second half of pregnancy, but that's not some future. It is a technology of the world we live in.